# Is it possible to have two different billing Currences under single tenant?

Tags: azure, currency, cost-management, azure-billing-api, azure-billing

I have a 4 subscriptions with billing currency of USD. and recently purchased a free trial subscription with INR as a billing currency. How Azure allowed this? Is this supported in Azure having multiple currencies under a single tenant?

Comment: It is entirely possible because Azure Subscription is the billing boundary and not Azure tenant. What that means is you get billed separately for each Azure Subscription.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about Azure billing and not related to programming.

Comment: But azure is not providing a option to chose a billing currency if i purchase Pay-as-you-go subscriptions

Comment: I believe it is based off of the billing address. I would recommend opening up a free billing support request with Azure. They should be able to resolve this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons why you might see multiple currencies include:

1. Azure subscriptions are associated with a billing account. Each billing account has a [billing address](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/change-azure-account-profile). Your billing currency is bound to this address. If you have subscriptions from different billing accounts with addresses in different countries, then you will see multile currencies within the same directory.
2. Cloud Solution Provider billing accounts support creating multiple [billing profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cost-management-billing/understand/mosp-new-customer-experience#billing-profiles), which each have separate currencies. This is another reason you might have multiple currencies, but these will be billed on separate invoices.
3. Some [Marketplace offers](https://learn.microsoft.com/marketplace/billing-invoicing) aren't supported in all billing currencies. In this case, there will be a fallback currency (typically USD, I believe).
4. I believe [subscription transfers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/billing-subscription-transfer) switch to the currency on the new billing account, but all historical cost will be from the old billing account. You won't see this cost from billing scopes, but you will see it when you look at cost from the subscription.
5. I'm not completely sure, but I believe there are also cases where reservations purchased on a different account (because of a subscription transfer) could also result in ongoing use of multiple currencies. I suspect this would be especially evident when viewing amortized costs.

I'm sure there are other scenarios. Hope this helps!